# Python 3.9.1, Mac Big Sur, Numpy and Essentia

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to install the Python package Essentia. I use the following brew recipe they provide:

```
brew install essentia --HEAD
```

On running, it notes the version of Python it finds:

```
→ Configuring for python3
python-config                            : /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8-config
```

but fails because:

```
Checking for python module 'numpy'                               : not found 
Could not find the python module 'numpy'
```

I have just upgraded to Big Sur and Python 3.9.1 by downloading the installer from the Python.org website. It says everything went fine on the installation, but when I type python --version into Terminal, it says the Python version is 3.7.6.

Hence, when I try to install numpy via pip install numpy, it says, "requirement already satisfied". I guess it is trying to install to this version?

I am now very confused. I installed Python 3.9.1, python --version shows 3.7.6 but v3.8 is found when I try to install Essentia.

How can I install numpy so Essentia can be installed correctly, and what is going on with all these different versions?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue today and I was able to install `numpy` by running:

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3 install numpy
```

This isn’t an ideal solution, but I figured I’d post it in case it helps.